# Segmentation fault with strcmp and copied char data

Tags: c++

I am working on an assignment and I keep getting segmentation fault in the following code from `main` that we are not allowed to change:

```
char signal[61];

Seti t2A(data, rF, rA, rB); // call constructor

t2A.getMessage(signal);            // calling member functions
t2A.getRanges(&pA, &pB);

usrF = t2A.getFrequency( );

if(strcmp(signal, correct)) { // <-- this is where i get segmentation fault.
```

The implementation of the `Seti` class:

```
class Seti {
    char signal[61];
    int freq;
    int a, b;
public:
    Seti(const char [ ], int, int, int);
    Seti();
    int getFrequency( );
    void getRanges(int *, int *);
    void setRanges(int , int );
    void getMessage(char *);
    bool replaceChar(int , char );
    bool copyPrimes(char *);
    bool copyFibonacci(char *);
    int initCap( );
    friend Seti join(Seti, Seti);
};
```

And the implementation of `getMessage`:

```
 void Seti::getMessage(char *pSignal) {
 strcpy (pSignal, signal);
 return;
 }
```

Why am I receiving a segmentation fault after that if statement in the main?

Comment: Where is correct set/declared - also if this is C++ signal and many of the function calls should use std::string

Comment: Have you checked what getMessage Returns?

Comment: the segfault in strcmp may happen if one of its arguments is not null-terminated..

Comment: where is `correct` defined?

Comment: correct is a string that says ""NON-SEQUITOR" and so should be signal. it was defined correctly since the prof is the one who coded it. 
getMessage returns void.
we have not yet learned std::string

Comment: Does that mean you cannot use `std::string`? It is easy enough to use. If you are trying to learn C I would understand.

Comment: I suppose the variable `correct` is not initialized (is `NULL`).

Comment: a printf of correct says "(null)" does that mean the prof coded it wrong?

Comment: I've removed the C tag because this is clearly C++.

Comment: Well, if `correct` is `NULL`, which the `printf` output suggests, somebody made a mistake. Whether that was you or the professor, I can't tell. (And, one of the things I hate, it's [**Non sequitur**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non_sequitur), with a **u**.)

Answer (score 1):

From that code, `Seti::signal` might be uninitialized and therefore not properly null-terminated, and `strcpy` corrupts memory, and this causes undefined behaviour, which luckily is segfault.

Use `strncpy` (remember adding terminating `'\0'` char at last array index yourself) or `snprintf` instead of `strcpy`, and also `strncmp` instead of `strcmp`.

Edit: ah, so `correct` is NULL after all (and not "NON-SEQUITOR"), based on your comment. Well, there is your problem. Could it be you have two variables with that name instead of one (a common beginner mistake)?

Above suggestion about using functions which allow specifying buffer size is still valid though.

Edit due to comment: it's useful to wrap `strncpy` to function like this, to avoid mistakes:

```
char *strncpy0(char *dst, const char *src, size_t n) {
  dst[n-1] = 0;
  return strncpy(dst, src, n-1);
}
```

Comment: No, don't use `strncpy`. See [my rant on the topic](http://the-flat-trantor-society.blogspot.com/2012/03/no-strncpy-is-not-safer-strcpy.html).

Comment: @KeithThompson strncpy is dangerous, yes, but lighter than snprintf and IMO just fine to use, C is a dangerous language anyway. But added a fixed version to answer anyway.

Comment: If you have enough information to use `strncpy()` (i.e., you can guarantee null termination and avoid padding), you might as well use `memcpy()` or `strcpy()`. A more reasonable replacement for `strncpy()` is `dst[0] = `'\0'`; strncat(dst, src, n);`. That does what most people probably expect `strncpy()` to do.

Comment: @KeithThompson Well, matter of opinion, but I expect to use strncpy0 like this with fixed size char *array* buffers: strncpy0(buf, src, sizeof buf);